# Start WSL in C:\Users\<username> via Microsoft Terminal

Tags: windows-terminal

As above, I want to by default open Ubuntu 22.04.1 (in WSL) through Microsoft Terminal in my Windows home directory `C:\Users\\<name\>`.

I've tried entering the default path as `C:\\Users\\\<name>` and as `/mnt/C/Users/\<name>`, as well as editing the JSON file directly, but each time I get the error:

```
Could not access starting directory _"\<choice of directory\>"_
```

... on start up. How would I get WSL to open in the Windows home directory?

Comment: I've found a work-around. Add the line ````cd /mnt/c/Users/\<name>```` to the end of ````.bashrc```` (I'm aware that this might not be the correct file to edit, but at least ````.bashrc```` is executed at every login, so I do end up in the correct directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the profile in Windows Terminal and change the command-line to be `wsl --cd C:\Users\%username%`.  The `--cd` argument can handle either Windows paths or Linux paths inside the WSL distribution.

The `%username%` is the CMD variable for the username, since Windows still uses the old (pre-PowerShell) variable style when launching applications.  You could, of course, hardcode it as well.

Keep in mind that file access under WSL2 is currently still *much* slower on Windows drives.

Comment: I'm aware it may be slower accessing Windows drives from the WSL command line, but I'm more familiar with the *sh command lines than Windows CMD or PowerShell, so I'm happy to take the performance hit for the limited number of things I do with it